# Jquery Promise Backbone Fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

What I want to achieve is the PopUpView only gets called-once all the Models have been saved.

When running the code, the popup view runs before the saves have completed.

```
var promises = []
_.each(exampleModels, _.bind(function (resource) {
    var filter = this.resources.get(resource.id);
    filter.fetch(
            {
                success: function (model, response) {
                    var participant = new Model({
                        example: "text"
                    });
                    promises.push(participant.save());
                }
            });
}, this));

$.when.apply($, promises).then(_.bind(function () {
    var popupForm = new PopUpView({

    });
    this.$el.append(popupForm.$el);
}, this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fetch` is asynchronous too. So when you hit the line `$.when.apply(...`, `promises` is an empty array. So the promise returned by `when` trigger the `then` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you show me how to do a double promise to fit the above code?

Comment: I'll mark as correct but I'd love if you could paste an example :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can take advantage of the [deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) return by `model.fetch` and `model.save`
2. And you can mutate your promise by having `then` [return a new promise](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#entry-longdesc)<sup>1</sup>

You could build your array of promises like this

```
var promises = _(ids).chain()
    .map(function(id) {
        // get the models you want 
        return c.get(id);
    })
    .map(function(model) { // build a promise for each model
        return model.fetch(). // promise returned by fetch
            then(function(resp) {
                var participant = new M({
                    example: "text"
                });
                return participant.save(); // promise returned by save
            });
    })
    .value();

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/du44m1ha/

<sup>1</sup> Since jQuery 1.8

Comment: I don't think this would work in the context of having it inside a loop right?

Comment: It would depend on the loop, `_.map` is basically a more readable loop